# Pop-up dialog using jQuery issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a problem with my page.  I have one view page and 2 forms in the same page.

The problem is that I have a main form and another form which is a  shown by JQuery.  My Problem is when I open the dialog box, submit its form and return the view, the dialog box diappears.  I don't know how to return a result which will still show the opened the dialog box.

I need your help on this please!

Below are the codes I used in my application.

**.CSTHML Forms**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login2", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "loginForm" }))
{
    <a id="submitlink" href="#" class="button button-large">Sign In</a>
}

// This is the pop-up dialog box
@using (Html.BeginForm("TroubleSubmit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "troubleSubmitForm" }))
{
    <a id="troubleSubmitLink" href="#" class="button">OK</a>
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('a#submitlink').click(function () {
            $('#loginForm').submit();
        });

$('a#troubleSubmitlink').click(function () {
            $('#troubleSubmitForm').submit();
        });
```

Below is the code of my controller action to handle the dialog form submit:

```
public ActionResult SignInTrouble(some parameter...)
    {
        // some operation and validation here

        return View(); // ??? What view will I return? When I return "Login" it will reload the page and close the dialog box.
    }
```

Again, how do I return the View that will still display the dialog box

Comment: Once you submit the form the page is reloaded. You should use an AJAX request instead if you don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Or an iFrame, I think the jQuery dialog handles them

Comment: can you give me some sample codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're submitting your form in a traditional (non-AJAX) manner so the page will reload. So you'll need to post in an AJAX way.

```
$("#submitlink").on("click", function () {
    var loginForm = $("#loginForm");

    $.ajax({
        url: loginForm.attr("action"),
        type: "post",
        data: loginForm.serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        // do something with the returned response
    });
});
```

The successful response is handled with `.done()` but what you return and how you handle the result is up to you. Simplest option is to return a partial view so it's just a html fragment to insert into an existing div container.

```
.done(function(result) {
    $("#someDiv").html(result);
});
```

I often return JSON with the view rendered as an html string `{ status: 0, message: "Success", html: "<div>..." }`. You could omit the html fragment from the JSON if you just need a simple YES/NO.

```
public ActionResult SignInTrouble(some parameter...)
{
    // some operation and validation here

    return Json({
        status: 1,
        message: "Validation Error"
    });
}
```

Then you get a few more possibilities with your response

```
.done(function(result) {
    var status = result.status;
    var message = result.message;
    if (status == 0) {
      // OK
    } else {
      // ERROR
    }
    $("#messageDiv").text(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply due to the page is reloaded, you must use ajax form in this case, so it'll only process the action of ajax form and then return the result to the form without reload the page

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("TroubleSubmit","Account", new AjaxOptions(){ ...... })
```

Comment: you mean to say, replace this "@using (Html.BeginForm("TroubleSubmit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "troubleSubmitForm" }))" with your suggestion, right?

Comment: that what i mean, but you must change somethings in AjaxOptions options to adapt your requirement.

Comment: I was now able to make the Ajax.BeginForm work, my question now is how do I return a validation error message to the dialog box?

Comment: In the `AjaxOptions` which has a property is `UpdateTargetId` which will be the place holder (id of an html element) for the result that is being returned by server, at server side you do a simple thing, just return a string result based on your validation return `Content("message from server")`